# @font-face only working locally

Tags: css, file, class, fonts, font-face

I have tried searching through many threads looking for an answer, but it seems like I've tried every solution. I have a font uploaded to eHost, and the CSS is pointed to that file. I'm using @font-face to have the user download the font. I have it downloaded already, so it's working locally, but not on the server.

```css
@font-face {
 font-family: BigNoodleTitling;
 src:url('Files/Fonts/big_noodle_titling.eot');
        src:url('Files/Fonts/big_noodle_titling.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
            url('Files/Fonts/big_noodle_titling.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
            url('Files/Fonts/big_noodle_titling.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
            url('Files/Fonts/big_noodle_titling.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
            url('Files/Fonts/big_noodle_titling.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
 src:local('BigNoodleTitling'); 
}
body {
 font-size: 100%;
 font-family: BigNoodleTitling, Helvetica, Helvetica Neue, DIN Condensed Bold, Avenir, Times New Roman;
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1.00);
}
.nav {
 max-width: 1000px;
 min-width: 320px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 padding-bottom: 1px;
 text-align: center;
}
.nav h2 {
 font-family: 'BigNoodleTitling'; 
 display: inline;
        font-size: 32px;
 padding: 10px;
 color: #FFB8BB;
 letter-spacing: 1.2px;
}
.nav h2 a {
 color: #FFB8BB;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.nav h2 a:hover {
 color: #A17477;
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

The website I'm running it through is: http://livelliottillustration.com/

Comment: Remove the `../` notation from `url(../` import statement on your live `CSS` file. Not needed.

Comment: Try re-loading the page. That issue should be corrected, but it's not working even with that fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@font-face` does not allow multiple `src` properties. Shrink it down like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: BigNoodleTitling;
  src: url('../Files/Fonts/big_noodle_titling.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('../Files/Fonts/big_noodle_titling.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('../Files/Fonts/big_noodle_titling.woff') format('woff'),
       url('../Files/Fonts/big_noodle_titling.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('../Files/Fonts/big_noodle_titling.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'),
       local('BigNoodleTitling');
}
```

*// part of old answer:*
Remove the `../` and it should work, since `Files` and `style.css` are both on root level.

If your font files are still not working, try using [FontSquirrel](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) to generate your font package.

Comment: I was actually messing with it, seeing if "../" would fix it. Sorry about that. The live version no longer has that, and it is still not working.

Comment: The font links are still wrong. You need to use `Files/Fonts/...`. Not just `Fonts/...`

Comment: Ug. Sorry again. Getting feedback from different places. Check again, I double checked to make sure the path was correct and it's still not working

Comment: Hm, ok. I need to inspect it a bit more then. But what you can try in the meantime - and I added it to my answer - use FontSquirrel to generate a webfont-package. https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Comment: @font-face {
    font-family: 'bignoodletitlingregular';
    src: url('big_noodle_titling-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('big_noodle_titling-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

I went ahead and uploaded the font files, that font squirrel created, on the same level as the CSS file. I used the above code to call the files. Still not working. Very odd...

Comment: Indeed. Btw, you have an invalid statement in your css file: `<STYLE type="text/css">`

Comment: Fixed that, but unfortunately it's not what is causing the issue. Thank you for inspecting this for me. I'm at a complete loss at this point.

Comment: Hey @AustinLovelace... I just had time to dive into it again. It looks like `@font-face` doesn't like your multiple `src` properties. I updated my solution. I hope it works for you now.

Comment: THAT WORKED! Thank you!